# Как отправить СМС из андроид с двумя СИМ карт?

Tags: android, sms

я написал код, который отправляет смс на определенный номер, но он работает тока на телефонах с 1 сим карт, как сделать, чтоб и с дуал сим тоже шли смски....можно ли поставит скажем отправка с первого сим, или из двух сразу..

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button button;
    EditText edittext;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String number = "номер телефона";
                String text = "текст";
                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(number,null,text,null,null);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Встречал такой пример, но работоспособность не проверял.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("service call isms 5 s16 "number" i32 0 i32 0 s16 "body"\n");
```

Мы получаем бонус с возможностью отправить смс из другого слота isms2, список доступных можно проверять в выводе команды service list

Comment: т.е. эту строку надо добавить вместо smsmanager или добавить к нему ???

Comment: код, который я привел - это Shell-команда, которая отправляет смс из 1-го слота сим.

Answer (score 0):

Сам столкнулся с такой проблемой. На просторах инета не так много информации. 
Возможно кому-то пригодится

На сегодня нашел 2 пути - 
Первый - это как описано [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/648485/292479)

```
        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("service call isms 5 s16 " + phoneNumber + " i32 0 i32 0 s16 " + message + "\n");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Второй вариант - это в настройках сим карт? выбрать отправку СМС на ту или иную карту

При первом варианте вы указываете сим карту программно?а во втором случае, вручную в настройках телефона